# kill not necessary services of crond

Tags: ubuntu, cron, etl, cron-task

I have some etl job scheduled in ubuntu

but from last couple of days, I'm receiving duplicate data. I have gone through all etl jobs, everything is fine.

I believe there is some problem in cron job services.

```
[root@user Desktop]# ps aux | grep cron
root       632  0.0  0.0 117244  1436 ?        Ss   Dec17   0:02 crond
root      9252  0.0  0.0 117204  1384 ?        Ss   14:15   0:00 crond
root     10045  0.0  0.0 103248   844 pts/57   S+   15:03   0:00 grep cron
```

When i run a pgrep crond

I get two numbers 632 and 9252. does it mean two services are running at the same time ? If yes can anyone help me how to kill not required process ?

Answer (score 0):

Stop the cron service gracefully, e.g. `service cron stop`.
Run the ps command again, the one still remains, should be killed.
Restart the cron service.

You may also check the syslog, cron.log for errors, to figure out why are there two cron process.